# How can I check if a variable is "loopable"?

Tags: php

I got a method that receives a parameter that could be any number of types.

It could be an array.

It could be an object that is in some way iterable such as a collection.

It could be something else altogether such as a string or integer which would throw

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How can I reliably check that the variable is "loopable" to avoid the warning?

I've tried `is_array()` as below but that only works for arrays:

```
if(is_array($mystery_type)){
    foreach($mystery_type as $value){
        ...
    }
}
```

I was surprised to not find an answer to this here, which probably means it's very simple and I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php

Comment: Do note that `[1, 2, 3] instanceof Traversable === false` though, so keep in mind to chain it like `$obj instanceof Traversable  || is_array($obj)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using **PHP 7.1+** you can use [`is_iterable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php):

```
if (is_iterable($mystery_type)) {
    // your loop
}
```

Or its **polyfill** (found in the [documentation comments](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-iterable.php#122574)):

```
if (!function_exists('is_iterable')) {
    function is_iterable($obj) {
        return is_array($obj) || (is_object($obj) && ($obj instanceof \Traversable));
    }
}
```

**Read more**: [`iterable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) pseudo-type (PHP 7.1+)

Comment: I'd like to add that this will exclude things like stdClass, so you may want to add an is_object() check to the function.

Comment: @Anther there is a `is_object` check in the polyfill already. I don't know what makes `stdClass` instances *loopable*, this could help improve the polyfill.

Comment: Only if the object is \Traversable. Back when I posted this I got burned by assuming the function would return true for anything that could successfully be passed into foreach which is why I posted the warning.  The polyfill doesn't address what I would've expected the function to do.  A "is_loopable" would probably help :P.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to not write methods that accept multiple types of data as input but to write smaller specific methods for each type of input. The code of such smaller methods is shorter, simpler, easier to read and understand (and to test).

The method for iterable data structures should use the [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface as the type of its argument:

```
public function f(Traversable $input) {
    // This foreach is guaranteed to always work
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        // Do something with $value and/or $key
    }
}
```

PHP triggers an error  when method `f()` is invoked with a value that does not implement the [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface.